# Failed RDP connection - Failed to Start Remote Desktop Session

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora, gnome

I have been trying for hours to solve this.

I have enabled RDP on my Fedora 39 through Gnome Settings -> Sharing -> Remote Desktop.

I have tried connecting through Remmina and xfreerdp.
It seems to be able to establish the connection looking at the logs for Remmina and xfreerdp, but it immediately gets terminated. When I check through `journalctl -f` on the server (my target), I see after my connection attempts using xfreerdp or Remmina I get the following message

```
gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[]:[WARN][com.winpr.negotiate] - AcceptSecurityContext status SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED []
gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[]:[WARN][com.winpr.negotiate] - AcceptSecurityContext status SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED []
gnome-remote-de[x]: Failed to start remote desktop session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Session creation inhibited
[ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_set_error_info:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRINFO_RPC_INITIATED_DISCONNECT []
```

I have been looking around on my system to no success trying to find some configuration file for gnome-remote-desktop, but since I enabled it through the "gnome GUI". It seems the configuration files for things enabled this way in Fedora/Gnome are placed somwhere I can't find. I'm assuming I have messed up/not fully understood, but I think it has something to do with number of active users connected etc.

Maybe finding this file could sort out my problems, or it might not. I dont know how to proceed